# is WCF necessary to send events to a remote StreamInsight hosted service

Tags: wcf, streaminsight

I am using StreamInsight 2.1 hosted as a windows service and want to send sensor events from a sensor server to it. Is it necessary to use WCF? If yes, please show me a good help to start.

Answer (score 0):

WCF is used for some administration functions but it is not required to send events to StreamInsight. StreamInsight does not ship with any adapters/sources/sinks. It is up to the developer to create them. If WCF is too bulky/slow/etc, you can use TCP, UDP, or any other protocol that you can work with in .NET.

Comment: I would be surprised if using `netTcpBinding` (binary over TCP/IP) would be too slow.

Comment: I am not familiar with WCF. Is it a slow service (regarding CEP applications)?

Comment: It depends on the amount of events coming through your application. Sometimes WCF has a higher overhead if you are doing things like SOAP.

Comment: WCF is a general mechanism and includes TCP/IP so i think it makes no sense to use something else instead of it!